# Is this review audit not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, migration

I'm a little confused regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557384/c-c-implementations-where-longjmp-unwinds), which I received during a review audit.

There doesn't seem to be any code to fix, and I see it as a request for recommendations for a C++ implementation that matched the questioner's requirements, which comes under Recommendations for Off-site Resources in my book. Alternatively it could come under discussion of appropriate platforms, which I would again consider as off-topic for SO and more in the realm of Programmers.

My action was to flag for moderator attention, explaining that I believed that it either belonged in Programmers and needed migration (if there was something to be gained from seeing it as a hypothetical), or that it should be closed for asking for resources.

Apparently it's a high-quality question, and I [failed the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5829588). I'm starting to doubt myself and need some external input on this.

Comment: Yeah it definitely smells like it's off-topic since it's asking people to find a compiler for them. I'm surprised it got so much positive attention as it's only a month old.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: there was a 300 bounty on that question, so likely increased number of upvotes it gained, and chances it acts as an audit

Comment: That was an absolutely dreadful question with zero odds at ever arriving at a useful answer.  But that's what's popular, the problem is real enough.  The OP is a notorious Windows hater, and demanded a non-Windows answer, he seems however oblivious at having picked a Windows answer.  Rather funny :)

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, he's asking for an implementation that, in his mind, does something that sucks, so he should be happy that he picked a Windows answer then. :)

Comment: @HansPassant I posted my answer there only after the OP clarified in the comments that Interix is sufficiently POSIX-like to meet his needs. He knows it's Windows. He already said that's okay. Not oblivious at all.

Comment: I just had the same issue with [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034904/more-efficient-way-to-write-this-algorithm) I failed the audit just for writing a comment that suggested to post this question on CodeReview instead.

Answer (score 6):

The review audits are often broken. This and nothing else is the reason you failed one.

As for the specific question, it is not a high quality one, yet it isn't bad enough to warrant a close. The OP is asking if a certain tool exists. He is not asking for tool recommendations and he isn't asking about where to find off-site resources. The question is narrow enough.

So the question is on-topic for the site, but I wouldn't call it a good question, I wouldn't upvote it and I would certainly not use it as some kind of example about how a good question should be. Again, the review audit is broken.

---

As for migrating things to the Programmers site... don't. You might naively think that a question about programming is on-topic for that site. Not so! It seems ridiculous, but I just now double-checked the Programmers posting policies, where we can read that questions concerning "coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs" are off-topic. So the question should not be migrated there, they would close it.

Comment: upvoted immediately after reading _[As for migrating things to the Programmers site... don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773)_!

Answer (score 5):

I would be cautious with language lawyer questions like this one.

What we're really looking for when we close recommendation questions are things like `icanhazblogsoftwarez` or `besttoolzrulez` questions.  Questions where you know that everyone and their brother is going to be chiming in with their favorites.

Questions like this often include no context to make answers meaningful, which is why the Software Recommendations site has specific rules for providing context.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense, what about migration to Programmers? Would that have been the appropriate action here? Or would it be better suited to stay on SO?

Comment: All of the C++ lawyers are on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of C++, namely that it has multiple implementations among different compilers due to the grey area created by "undefined behavior", this question could trivially be reformulated so as to be more in line with a proper Stack Overflow structure but also be rendered completely meaningless in the context of C++:

> <strike>[...] where</strike>does the longjmp function "unwind<strike>s</strike>", i.e. <strike>where</strike>does it interact<strike>s</strike> with destructors for automatic-storage objects, **attribute**((**cleanup**(...))), POSIX threads cancellation handlers, etc. rather than just restoring the register context saved by setjmp?

Such a question about how to use a language is not trivial and would be on topic, but there's no answer due to the variations among compilers and the lack of a concrete answer from the standard.  Most languages don't have to deal with this, but I don't think it's a good idea to say these more esoteric areas of C++ don't fit on the site because of that, nor do I think anyone is interested in propagating a plethora of compiler specific tags.

As others have said, it's not going into the hall of fame or anything, but it doesn't deserve to be closed nor should it be moved.  That doesn't make it a good audit, though.